# Screenshot of a scrollable page in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I want to take the screenshot of a full page in google chrome without using any extensions or apps

Comment: I don't think without using Chrome extension it is possible. To use extension see this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl

Comment: But I can't use extensions , it is blocked.Thanks for your reply

Comment: This cannot be done without an extension

Comment: Can you use a portable app from a USB stick? If so try [Screenshot Captor](https://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/screenshotcaptor/)

Comment: I cannot understand downvoting, the answer of @Amit Agarwal proved it possible. Thank you for the question and the answer, that was helpful.

Comment: Some OSes (e.g. Android) have this functionality built in, Which OS are you on?

Answer (score 12):

This can be achieved in Chrome as of v59:

[Announcement in the developer blog](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#screenshots)

[Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_6_9eFPhxI)

Summary of steps (if you prefer text):

1. Open Developer tools
2. Toggle the device toolbar
3. Set the desired resolution in the device toolbar
4. Select the More options overflow menu in the device toolbar
5. Select Capture screenshot or Capture full size screenshot
6. The screenshot will be saved to your Downloads folder

Comment: On very long pages, this still does not capture the entire page. I don't see all of my content and there are still scrollbars.

Comment: The maximum is about 10k pixels tall.

Answer (score 0):

You could take several screenshots with `Print`, save them with `Paint` and stack them with a program like [Microsoft Image Composite Editor](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/ice/).

Answer (score 0):

Also see [Web Screenshots](http://ctrlq.org/screenshots/), a web app that works in all browsers.

Comment: But doesn't work on logged in pages.

Answer (score -1):

You can check out [Fireshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/capture-webpage-screensho/mcbpblocgmgfnpjjppndjkmgjaogfceg?hl=en-US) a chrome extension. It includes these options;

- Capture entire page.
- Capture Visible part.
- Capture Selection.