# Full-page-screenshot without third-party extension with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

In Chrome, I discovered that:

- F12 (Developer tools)
- CTRL+SHIFT+P
- Screenshot > "Capture full size screenshot"

[image]

creates a full page PNG screenshot.

**Is there a way to have a keyboard shortcut for this in Chrome, without any third party tool/extension?**

Comment: Windows or Linux or Mac? Would printing on a PDF be considered a solution?

Comment: Windows, and not really about PDF printing @harrymc. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: You would still need some additional software. Is the tool AutoHotkey acceptable?

Comment: If AutoHotkey is acceptable, then see the answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screenshot of a scrollable page in chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/955763/screenshot-of-a-scrollable-page-in-chrome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44851234/11036999) on StackOverflow from a person working on the DevTools team who says it is **not possible**.

There are 2 comments to the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838370/) regarding 2 issues created on the Chromium Bugs platform, you can track their progress to know when and if the features might be available -

1. [Requesting the ability to customise existing keyboard shortcuts](https://crbug.com/174309) (#174309)
2. Specifically what this question wants - [A keyboard shortcut to take a screenshot from DevTools](https://crbug.com/743765) (#743765)

So, this is definitely not possible natively inside Chrome, but can be made possible using third-party tools like AutoHotKey as mentioned in [*harrymc*'s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1567124/995873) or by using an extension [like this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl) which the OP prohibits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. Even if it doesn't answer the question, it does provide closure ;)

Answer (score 3):

There are several extensions that will take a screenshot of the entire page,
but the post demands no Chrome extensions.

A solution that uses instead the free key-remapping product
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
can remap some key for printing the entire Windows by simulating the
sequence of keys described in the post.

The following AutoHotkey script will issue the above entire sequence
when the <kbd>F9</kbd> key is pressed:

```
F9::
Send, {F12}                        ; send F12
Sleep, 400                         ; wait for the developer tools window
Send, ^+P                          ; send ctrl+shift+P
Sleep, 400                         ; wait
Send, Capture full size screenshot ; send the command text
Sleep, 400                         ; wait
Send, {Enter}                      ; send the Enter key
Sleep, 2000                        ; wait while the page is generated
Send, {Enter}                      ; send Enter to store the image in default folder
```

If the waits (in milliseconds) are not long enough, then increase them.

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't answer the question **without using any third party tools/extensions** :(

Comment: @SirExotic: In that case the answer would probably a really complicated PowerShell script. You could start on the basis of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535311/powershell-scroll-down-a-webpage-powershell-screenshot). The problem would be to scroll the page, if larger than the screen. You would need a method such as: take screenshot, scroll page, take screenshot, compare to last one and (1) if identical, stop, (2) If not identical, compare and combine its upper portion with the lower portion of the previous one. I'm certainly not volunteering to write that script.