# How to capture a web page larger than the browser window?

Tags: browser, screenshot

How do I "capture" (e.g. screenshot) an entire web page in 2021 that is both wider and taller than my browser window or screen? Thanks.

Comment: No, those are 10 year old answers. Those are nearly all dead links. Please check first before posting.

Comment: It depends which browser you are using. Which browser are you trying to capture the web page in? For example in Chrome it would be: https://superuser.com/questions/1501347/full-page-screenshot-without-third-party-extension-with-chrome

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the browser you are using but this can now be achieved natively in most browsers.

#### Firefox

1. Right click on the page
2. Take Screenshot

[image: Take Screenshot]

3. Save full page

[image: Save full page]

4. Then you can choose to **Copy** or **Download** the image

#### Edge

1. Right click on the page
2. Web capture

[image: Web capture]

3. Capture full page

[image: Capture full page]

4. Then you can choose to **Save**, **Add to Collections**, **Copy**, or **Share**